# How to block IOS devices from accessing certain DNS links

Tags: ios, linux, mobile, dns

I'm new to networking so please tell me if this isn't allowed, I'm also not to sure how to even ask this question, or if I'm even asking the right question.

Ok, I want to create a .mobileconfig file that will connect on demand to my server, and block a few ad DNS names so all the traffic on my iPhones will be processed through a "DNS blocker" on a linux Ubuntu server, yet I can't find any information on how to do this. I don't know how to search for it as everything I search fails to be what I'm looking for. I have the mobile configuration file ready to go, but I can not figure out how to make the phone send it's traffic through a file that says block "apple.com" for example.
I hope this makes sense, sorry for the noob post, I'm just trying to learn and I can't find help.

Edit: need help on the software side of routing all traffic through DNS blocker Ubuntu Linux vps, have ssh root access

Comment: This site is for asking programming questions. Please delete this question and post it in a more appropriate site.

Comment: What do you mean? Please help me figure out where to go at least I can't find where to go and everyone tells me to go somewhere else, it's like nobody just wants to help anymore and I'm about to shove my computer science class in the can cause nobody fing helps me with shit